# What does the following command do?

Tags: linux, android

What does the following command do?

```
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

When I typed mount --help on shell I could find out -o is for options. But can not understand why the , between remount,rw.

If any one can explain the complete command please. I read the above command while I was trying  to remove some [BloatWare](http://limitlessdroid.com/2010/08/28/rooting-101-bloatware/) from my LG Optimus One p500 , after rooting it.

Comment: I don't know why this was migrated *from* SU...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this on for size:

- mount: the actual command
- -o remount,rw: the option passed to mount (remount means dismount, and remount; rw means mount as read/write) The -o flag can take several comma separated parameters.
- -t yaffs2: use the yaffs2 filesystem type
- /dev/block/mtdblock3: mount the block device found at /dev/block/mtdblock3
- /system: mount the specified block device at /system